# Vuforia - create tap on object function

Tags: android, eclipse, augmented-reality, vuforia

I've made 5(five) 3D object showed with vuforia eclipse project, now i want each of these 5 object have a tap function :
 1. first object-->when i touch 1 icon, it's linked to website
 2. second object--> to open gallery
 3. third object --> to open file (such as pdf)
 4. forth object --> open such a file also
 5. close application.

please help me in this case, any help will be appreciate.
thanks,

regards

Comment: Are you developing for iOS, Android, or Unity?

Answer (score 0):

I use Android as an operating system.
@ashatte

Answer (score 0):

You should look into the Video Playback sample application: [here](https://developer.vuforia.com/resources/sample-apps/video-playback-sample-app?t=android-3371282).

Particularly, the **isTapOnScreenInsideTarget()** method found in `VideoPlayback.cpp`:

```
JNIEXPORT bool JNICALL
Java_com_qualcomm_QCARSamples_VideoPlayback_VideoPlayback_isTapOnScreenInsideTarget(JNIEnv *env, jobject, jint target, jfloat x, jfloat y)
{
    //LOG("Java_com_qualcomm_QCARSamples_VideoPlayback_VideoPlayback_isTapOnScreenInsideTarget");
    // Here we calculate that the touch event is inside the target
    QCAR::Vec3F intersection, lineStart, lineEnd;

    SampleMath::projectScreenPointToPlane(inverseProjMatrix, modelViewMatrix[target], screenWidth, screenHeight,
                              QCAR::Vec2F(x, y), QCAR::Vec3F(0, 0, 0), QCAR::Vec3F(0, 0, 1), intersection, lineStart, lineEnd);

    // The target returns as pose the center of the trackable. The following if-statement simply checks that the tap is within this range
    if ( (intersection.data[0] >= -(targetPositiveDimensions[target].data[0])) && (intersection.data[0] <= (targetPositiveDimensions[target].data[0])) &&
         (intersection.data[1] >= -(targetPositiveDimensions[target].data[1])) && (intersection.data[1] <= (targetPositiveDimensions[target].data[1])))
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}
```

Then you should look inside `VideoPlayback.java` at the **mGestureDetector** code, as that is where touch events are detected by the Android Activity and the native method is called.

```
mGestureDetector = new GestureDetector(
            getApplicationContext(), mSimpleListener); 

// Set the double tap listener:
mGestureDetector.setOnDoubleTapListener(new OnDoubleTapListener()
{
    /** Handle the double tap */
    public boolean onDoubleTap(MotionEvent e)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < NUM_TARGETS; i++)
        {
            // Verify that the tap happens inside the target:
            if (isTapOnScreenInsideTarget(i, e.getX(), e.getY()))
                // Do what you need to do here
        }
    }
}
```

Essentially, you need to copy the relevant methods and files into your project (whether it is FrameMarkers or ImageTargets) from the VideoPlayback sample application. It's difficult to be more specific because achieving this requires a lot of small code changes, but this should get you started...

Comment: Is it possible to achieve the same without native code? I want to make this happen with pure java.